# Composer: multiple vendor directories (zend seperate dir than doctrine,...)

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php

I've new to composer and I searched a few hours on the internet to find a solution for my problem, I've found one but can't get it to work so it's probably me.

I'm starting a new project with zend framework 1.12.3 and some extra vendors like doctrine. I don't mind that doctrine, phpunit, ... are installed in the default /vendor (or if I set another) but I rather have Zend on library/Zend instead of vendor/zendframework/....

I'm new to composer so I could've missed something.

Original:

```
{
    "name": "Awesome",
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zendframework1": "1.12.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.3.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.21",
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev"
    }
}
```

I also tried it with https://github.com/composer/installers

```
{
    "name": "Awesome",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "~1.0"
        "zendframework/zendframework1": "1.12.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.3.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.21",
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "library/Zend": ["zendframework/zendframework1"]
        }
    }
}
```

If it's a too big hastle to do it I can install zend locally so that's not a problem but it would be nice to do it with composer at once.

Comment: I wonder why you'd want to do this. It does not matter where the files are as long as they are properly autoloaded, IMHO. And if you argue that the Zend files should be there for easier access, then why not Doctrine as well? You can define the directory where EVERYTHING is installed, so if you don't like the name "vendor", feel free to define a different one.

Comment: Hehe, was just thinking about it if it was possible cause I like vendor as a name but want to have zend installed as the default place because I use zend server Ok than something else, composer saves it on vendor/zendframework/zendframework1 can I change that easily?

Comment: no, you can't. That directory structure is build that way because that's conventions the Composer autoloader uses. If you change it, the autoloader wouldn't find you classes anymore

Comment: Ok great, I think i'm going to install zend without composer and just use composer for all other dependencies. Or would it be possible to download zend in the default vendor/zendframework/zendframework1 when development (so the autoloader points to that directory) but on production it points to another directory? (I'm talking about doing this in composer.json). (just say no if it's not possible at all :))

Comment: No. Why would you do that? Zend Server has it's own version of Zend Framework, but you usually won't want to use it, because most of the time it is the wrong version anyway. For the same reason PEAR never really kicked ass, because a central installation of THE version to use will install the wrong version - let alone updating it is a major pain as well. Composer allows every application to use their version of choice.

Comment: I follow your thought pattern and you are right. So I should stick with the normal way of composer.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, its not possible to install different packages in different(custom) locations.

the installer-paths does not work, as the zend package is not of a supported type (I think this works only for wordpress packages)

For your problem this is not a real problem. Zend Server sure does nothing special, only because the libraries are placed in this specific place. Also they had enough time to fix things for composer, if they really had some.

But, even if its not a solution for placing the Zend framework in this specific place, its possible to have multiple composer.json in different directories. You only need to add both autoload.php files. Thats no problem, as composer supports autoloading for multiple usage as this.